# woocommerce hide shipping methods conditionally on number

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

If there are more than 15 articles in a cart. How can I force just one desired shipping method (i.e. DHL) and hide all other shipping methods?

I already have the plugin "flexible shipping" but prefer a hook in functions.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will enable only one defined shipping method if there is more than 15 articles in cart:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_methods_based_on_item_count', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_methods_based_on_item_count( $rates, $package ) {
    // HERE the targeted shipping method ID (see the attribute "value" of the related shipping method input field)
    $targeted_method_id = 'flat_rate:12'; // <== Replace with your DHL shipping method ID

    // HERE the articles count threshold
    $more_than = 15;

    // Cart items count
    $item_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    if( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() > $more_than ) {
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
            if ( $rate->id != $targeted_method_id ) {
                unset($rates[$rate_key]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Tested and works.

> **Refresh the shipping caches:** *(required)*
>
> 1. This code is already saved on your active theme's function.php file.
> 2. The cart is empty
> 3. In a shipping zone settings, disable / save any shipping method, then enable back / save.
>
> **You are done** and you can test it.

Comment: Thank you very much Loic.

We have several shipping Zones. How can your code modified to target the Shipping Method via its Name ("1st Class") instead of its instance_id?